# Square root inside a square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Hi guys I just want to ask how to solve this.

The given is:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$$

then solve for the $$(f \circ f)(x)$$

then it becomes.
$$(f \circ f)(x)=f(f(x))$$
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}$$
Can the expression be simplified?

Comment: $\sqrt[4]x$ could be a good idea, I hope. Think about $\sqrt x=x^{1/2}$

Comment: $\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}=x^{1/4}$. Is this what you want?

Comment: I just want to know if it can be simplified

Comment: You mean like [a root within a root within a root](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666) ? :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\sqrt{x} = x^{1/2}$ so $\sqrt{\sqrt{x}} = (x^{1/2})^{1/2} = x^{1/4} = \sqrt[4]{x}$.

Comment: So if that is the answer. Is the domain [0, + ∞)?

Comment: That is indeed the domain.

Answer (score 2):

As we have the unwritten index $2$ for the sqare root, we multiply it by the index of the root inside the first root.
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt[2\times2]{x}= \sqrt[4]{x}$$

Another example is:
$$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[4]{x}} = \sqrt[3\times4]{x}= \sqrt[12]{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

The nth root of a number $a$: $\;\sqrt[\large n] a = a^{1/n}$.

The square root of the square root of x is therefore $$\sqrt{\sqrt x} = (\sqrt x)^{1/2} = (x^{1/2})^{1/2} = x^{1/4} = \sqrt[\large 4] x$$

Since the domain of $\sqrt x$ is $[0, + \infty)$, this is also the domain of $\sqrt{\sqrt x} = x^{1/4}$.